# How I can uninstall without trace files from console? even with the program folder eg gimp uninstall

Tags: uninstall, gimp

How I can uninstall without trace files from console? even with the program folder eg gimp uninstall
i use

```
sudo apt-get –purge remove gimp
sudo apt-get clean gimp
```

and nothig the folder still appear in my personal folder

Comment: That means that with these commands is sufficient to uninstall? sudo apt-get –purge remove gimp sudo apt-get clean gimp

Comment: Yes, aside from configuration files, which are stored in `~/`. See A.B.'s answer

Answer (score 3):

The package manager **never** removed files from your personal folder (If this should be the case, but then the package maintainer has worked poorly.). These files or folders you always have to remove yourself.

In your case, E.G.

```
rm -r ~/.gimp-2.8
```

`2.8` depends on your Gimp version.